# Convert LPWSTR to v8::String

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

```
LPWSTR dscStr = "TEST STRING AAAAAA";

char buffer[5000];
wcstombs(buffer, dscStr, sizeof(dscStr));

return scope.Close(String::New(buffer)); // FAILED
```

I need to convert LPWSTR(or LPCWSTR) to v8::String.

Comment: Shouldn't you write `L"TEST STRING AAAAAA"` (note `L` before string)? Also, I believe `sizeof(dscStr) == sizeof(void*)`, you should use `wcslen` here.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've posted shouldn't even compile, since you're trying to assign a `char const *` to a `wchar_t *`.

This should work (I don't know anything about `v8::String` so I'm assuming the constructor call in the last line is correct)

```
LPCWSTR dscStr = L"TEST STRING AAAAAA";
// LPCWSTR is an alias for wchar_t const *
// The L before the string literal indicates it is a wide string literal

char buffer[5000];
wcstombs( buffer, dscStr, wcslen(dscStr) );
// Need wcslen to compute the length of the string

return scope.Close(String::New(buffer));
```

Comment: dscStr is returned value by function.

Comment: @HKPR_BE The code above should still work in that case; just make sure you use `wcslen` to get the string length, instead of `sizeof`